# Can I mock Kotlin service into java Junit test

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I'm currently writing Junit test with Mockito in java. But one microservice is written in Kotlin.
I try to mock the kotlin service, but it doesn't work as I excepted.
I plan to return a customize response inside the test, I checked it with debugger, instead of returning the response, it always runs into the kotlin function(getFile).

```
@Mock
private FileService fileservice;   // this service written in Kotlin

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Response respone = new Response(...);
    when(fileservice.getFile(any())).thenReturn(response);
}
```

Comment: Most likely a result of the Kotlin service impl not being marked `open`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you, Louis. You are right! Thank you so much.

Comment: We using Mockk for mocking of kotlin objects quite a lot, since it is optimized for kotlin, it should works better than Mockito for kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use mocking library designed for Kotlin, there is few options for this:

- If still needed to stick to mockito, there is official mockito support for kotlin, more details here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin
- Also there is mockk library that specially designed for kotlin, and it better fits than mockito: https://mockk.io/

Also many java libraries using byte-code generated proxies like mockito does, while kotlin makes every class final by default, there is a kotlin plugin named all-open, which can make all needed classes open: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html